# Ruby: match first, second, this etc elements from a dimensional array

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have an array of arrays. I want to concatenate the first, second, third elements of arrays.

Example arrays:

```
a =  [[4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3], [8, 9, 10]]
a1 = [[1, 2, 3], [8, 9, 10]]
a2 = [[4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3], [8, 9, 10], [11, 21, 31]]
```

Output:

```
out of a:  [[4,1,8],[5,2,9],[6,3,10]]
out of a1: [[1,8],[2,9],[3,10]]
out of a2: [[4,1,8,11],[5,2,9,21],[6,3,10,31]]
```

Comment: I cannot parse the title.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `transpose` method

```
a.transpose
 => [[4, 1, 8], [5, 2, 9], [6, 3, 10]]
```

Answer (score 1):

[Array#`transpose`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-transpose):

```
[a, a1, a2].map(&:transpose)
# [
#   [[4, 1, 8], [5, 2, 9], [6, 3, 10]],
#   [[1, 8], [2, 9], [3, 10]],
#   [[4, 1, 8, 11], [5, 2, 9, 21], [6, 3, 10, 31]]
# ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Whenever `Array#transpose` can be used so can [Enumerable#zip](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-zip).

```
a.first.zip *a.drop(1)
  #=> [[4,1,8],[5,2,9],[6,3,10]]
```